# On error in global.asax can't do server.transfer

Tags: .net, global-asax, server.transfer

In my global.asax page I have the following code:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
     server.transfer("err.aspx")
End Sub
```

It does not work and I get the folowing error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend using the built-in error handling in .NET for this, just use Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="err.aspx" redirectMode="responseRewrite">
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The `responseRewrite` will make it act as a Server.Transfer. If you want a redirect instead, use `redirectMode="responseRedirect"`.

More info here:

- http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.customerrorssection.redirectmode.aspx

However, if you really want to handle it in Global.asax, you should use the `sender` object:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
     Dim app As HttpApplication = CType(sender, HttpApplication)
     app.Server.Transfer("err.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer. I tried                                     Dim server As HttpApplication = CType(sender, HttpApplication)
server.Transfer("err.aspx")                                            as you mentioned but i get error: transfer is not a member of httpaplication